# PostgreSQL: access right problems

Tags: postgresql, users, role, permissions, postgresql-9.5

I have a "production" user and database on which I want to give right access on all the users belonging to a production group.

Unfortunately, I don't succeed, keeping the access denied error.

Can you have a look at the example script below and tell me what I missed (production user/database is `toto` and production group is `toto_group`)?

Some comments:

- The use case is: The data loading is already in production. Developpers (`titi`, etc.) now only have to read the data, and we want them to read it from the production database in order to avoid having to duplicate everything.
- I've initially tried on Linux, but I did the test script on windows. Same results.
- I'm using postgresql 9.5
- I have also tried to grant the access to the tables instead of the schema. Same results.

Thanks a lot.

```
\c postgres postgres

DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS toto;
DROP TABLESPACE IF EXISTS toto_ts;
DROP ROLE IF EXISTS toto;
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS titi;
DROP TABLESPACE IF EXISTS titi_ts;
DROP ROLE IF EXISTS titi;
DROP ROLE IF EXISTS toto_group;

CREATE ROLE toto_group NOLOGIN;

CREATE ROLE toto WITH PASSWORD 'toto' LOGIN;
CREATE TABLESPACE toto_ts OWNER toto LOCATION 'd:/pg_ts/toto';
CREATE DATABASE toto TABLESPACE=toto_ts TEMPLATE=template0 OWNER=toto;
GRANT toto_group TO toto;

CREATE ROLE titi WITH PASSWORD 'titi' LOGIN;
CREATE TABLESPACE titi_ts OWNER titi LOCATION 'd:/pg_ts/titi';
CREATE DATABASE titi TABLESPACE=titi_ts TEMPLATE=template0 OWNER=titi;
GRANT toto_group TO titi;

COMMIT;

\c toto

DROP SCHEMA public;
CREATE SCHEMA s_test;
SET SCHEMA 's_test';
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA s_test TO toto_group;
CREATE TABLE t_test (id INTEGER);

COMMIT;

\c titi

DROP SCHEMA public;
CREATE SCHEMA s_test;
SET SCHEMA 's_test';
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA s_test TO toto_group;
CREATE TABLE t_test (id INTEGER);

COMMIT;
```

Comment: The script you showed gives no error. Please share exact command that generates the error, plus exact error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also grant access to the database and `SCHEMA` itself:

```
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE toto TO toto_group;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA s_test TO toto_group;
```